# Integrate Dynamics crm api, get adfs token

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to integrate the Dynamics crm api. I am using [this](https://jlattimer.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-php.html) code example to get a token from adfs. In the sample code, it is supposed to get the looged in username, but I am getting 302 response code.

Can someone pls help me on how to resolve this 302. When I pass the token to the crm api, I get 400 response code.

We are using Dynamics crm with adfs/IFD.